# Getting "403 - Unauthorized" error when accessing a resource

Tags: php, laravel, user-permissions

I am encountering a "403 - Unauthorized" error when trying to access a specific resource in my Laravel application. I have implemented a permissions and roles system, but I seem to be missing something. Here are the details of my setup:

- Laravel version: 8.0
- Permissions and roles and users: I have a permissions table, a roles table, a user table and a pivot table permission_role to establish the many-to-many relationship between them. Users are associated with roles through the role_user pivot table.
  Middleware: I have created a CheckPermission middleware to handle the authorization logic based on the user's assigned permissions.
  Authentication: I am using Laravel's built-in authentication system with the auth middleware applied to the routes.

Problem:
When I try to access the /softwares route, which requires the view:software permission, I receive a "403 - Unauthorized" error. However, in my user's roles, I have assigned the view:software permission.

Code:
Here is the relevant code:

**routes/web.php:**

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'check.permission:view:software'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/softwares', SoftwaresController::class)->names('softwares');
});
```

**app/Http/Middleware/CheckPermission.php:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
{
    if (!$request->user()->hasAnyPermission($permissions)) {
        abort(403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**app/Models/User.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {

        if ($value) {
            $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
        }
    }

    public function hasAnyPermission($permissions)
    {
        $userPermissions = $this->role()
        ->with('permissions')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('permissions')
        ->flatten()
        ->pluck('name')
        ->toArray();

    if (is_array($permissions)) {
        return count(array_intersect($userPermissions, $permissions)) > 0;
    }

    return in_array($permissions, $userPermissions);
    }

}
```

**SoftwareController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Software;
use App\Models\Permission;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests\Softwares\StoreSoftwareRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Softwares\UpdateSoftwareRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SoftwaresController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('can:view software')->only(['index', 'show']);
        $this->middleware('can:create software')->only(['create', 'store']);
        $this->middleware('can:update software')->only(['edit', 'update']);
        $this->middleware('can:delete software')->only('destroy');
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        $softwares = Software::all();
        return Inertia::render('Softwares/Index', compact('softwares'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->authorize('create:software');
        return Inertia::render('Softwares/Create');
    }

    public function store(StoreSoftwareRequest $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create:software');

        $softwares = Software::create([
            // Software creation logic...
        ]);

        return Redirect::route('softwares.index')
            ->with('message', 'Software created successfully');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $softwares = Software::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('update:software', $softwares);

        return Inertia::render('Softwares/Edit', [
            'softwares' => $softwares,
        ]);
    }

    public function update(UpdateSoftwareRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $softwares = Software::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('update:software', $softwares);

        $softwares->update($request->all());

        return Redirect::route('softwares.index')
            ->with('message', 'Software updated successfully');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $softwares = Software::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('delete:software', $softwares);

        $softwares->delete();

        return Redirect::route('softwares.index')
            ->with('message', 'Software deleted successfully');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $softwares = Software::findOrFail($id);
        $this->authorize('view:software', $softwares);

        return Inertia::render('Softwares/Show', compact('softwares'));
    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserValidator::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'check.permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
    ];
```

What I've tried:

- I have verified that the hasAnyPermission() method in the User model is correctly receiving the permissions array.
- I have checked the database, and the user has the view:software permission assigned to their role.
- I have also tried clearing the cache and re-logging in to ensure the permissions are properly loaded.

Expected behavior:
When a user has the view:software permission assigned to their role, they should be able to access the /software route without encountering a "403 - Unauthorized" error.

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. I need to implement permission for CRUD of Software based on roles and roles assigned to user. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `Gate`

You need to define (in your Provider --> ex. `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`) every permission what you want will use on your code.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

Gate::define('create: software', function ($user) {
  return $user->hasPermission('create:software'); // check that user has permission for "create:software";
});
```

You can basically retrieve every permission from Laravel and define them using a foreach loop:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

$permissions = Permission::get();
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  Gate::define($permission, function ($user) use ($permission) {
    return $user->hasPermission($permission);
  });
}
```

[Writing Gates on Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#writing-gates) - Laravel Docs

#### Now working `$this->authorize`

```php
$this->authorize('create:software'); // will return 403 error response if not allowed, else do nothing
```

[Via Controller Helpers on Laravel (authorize)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) - Laravel Docs

Thats "helper" called `Gate::authorize()` function with `$user` data, and will run the defined function that will return `true` or `false`.

If not allowed this permission for user, then `authorize()` automatically return with 403 error response.

However, if you need only `true` or `false` result without automatically response, will can use `can()` function.

```php
$this->can('create:software'); // return true or false
```

Thats "helper" just called `Gate::allows()` function.

[Authorization Actions via Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) - Laravel Docs